# apostrophe [ ' ] not save in database

Tags: php

Values don't save in database when I use : **apostrophe** [ ' ]

I changed database collation to "**utf8_general_ci**" &  column type to **BLOB**.

**addslashes** :

```
<td <?php if($userdepart==0 ) { ?>
    contenteditable="true"
    onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'name','<?php echo addslashes($orderrecords[$k]["id"]); ?>')"
    <?php } ?>>
    <?php echo substr(addslashes($orderrecords[$k]["name"]),0,75); ?>
</td>
```

Also I tried **mysqli_real_escape_string**

```
<td <?php if($userdepart==0 ){?>
    contenteditable="true"
    onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'name','<?php echo addslashes(mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$orderrecords[$k]["id"])); ?>')"
    <?php }?>>
    <?php echo addslashes(mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,substr($orderrecords[$k]["name"],0,975))); ?>
</td>
```

Right now I really can't use prepared statements and parameterized queries, as this is used by only company users. Please help me with a work around....

**update**

```
function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {

    if(column=="image_ready" || column=="ready_to_print" || column=="ready_to_packaging" || column=="ready_to_dispatch"){cvalue=editableObj;}else{var cvalue=$(editableObj).text();}

      $.ajax({
        url: "editOrder.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:'column='+column+'&editval='+cvalue+'&id='+id,
        success: function(data){
          $(editableObj).css("background","#dddddd");
          if(column=="image_ready" || column=="ready_to_print" || column=="ready_to_packaging" || column=="ready_to_dispatch"){location.reload();}
        }
      });
```

**editOrder.php**

```
$sql = "UPDATE do_order set " . $_POST["column"] . " = '".$_POST["editval"]."' WHERE  id=".$_POST["id"];
```

Comment: It sounds like you're giving yourself an SQL injection. but you also need to provide your code that actually saves to the database for us to help.

Comment: Your `saveToDatabase` function seems to be JavaScript, is it doing an AJAX request to some PHP script? You should do the string escape in that server script and not on the client, it can easily be manipulated like that.

Comment: @PhilCross thanks for comment, please check `update` part in question.....

Comment: @xander thanks for comment, please check `update` part in question.....

Comment: _"Right now I really can't use prepared statements and parameterized queries, as this is used by only company users."_ - Why does it matter who's using the app? You're currently setting yourself up for failure. Just use prepared statements and your issue will be no more.

Comment: The problem is that you're using `$_POST['...']` directly in your SQL. So, because you're not using prepared statements, your SQL is actually looking something like this: `UPDATE do_order SET some_column = 'Fore'name'` Which is sql injection and very dangerous. You really do need to use prepared statements, or at the very least, escape your queries.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks for suggestion, this is old & big project  , we will surely redesign the entire project bu following proper method......

Comment: This isn't something that requires a redesign. It's always going to break if someone uses apostophes and you don't escape or use prepared queries. It's super dangerous the way it's currently working. There's nothing stopping a user from deleting all the data in your tables at the moment, if someone posts something like `'; DELETE FROM some_table; --` in a form, you're database is going to execute a delete statement.

Comment: @PhilCross I got your point, thanks for your time, we will go for prepared statements.....

Comment: @PhilCross - In all fairness, `mysqli_query()` doesn't actually execute multiple queries in one call. You would need to use `mysqli_multi_query()` for that. But as you mention in your comment, there are other risks.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I haven't used Mysql* functions in a long time :D thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use prepared statements:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $firstname, $lastname, $email);
$firstname = "John";
$lastname = "D'''oe";
$email = "john@example.com";
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: thanks for answer, sorry i dont want to use prepared statements for some reason.... can you please tell me what i can do solve issue , here is full code : https://pastebin.com/pZsnT1YK

Comment: @vickeycolors _"i dont want to use prepared statements for some reason"_ - Because? You got an answer that will most likely solve your issue (and protect you from SQL injections), why would you _not_ want to use it?

Comment: okay, so how about you str_replace() all apastrophes with a char that looks similar, like this one: ’

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks for comment , as this is internal project used only by company users , also as this is old project, we need some workaround now, later we redesign this project by following proper methods......

Comment: @vickeycolors - Well, if you don't care about taking our advice and solutions, I'm out.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson you are absolutely right , i will surely consider your advice,  thanks for your time, we will go for prepared statements.....